# Add a button to the Gutenberg editor header

Tags: block-editor

**Hi There**

I want to add a button to the header of Gutenberg editor, in the place displayed on that picture here:

[image]

One solution is to use javascript, but I am wondering if there's some kind of filters

Thank You!

Comment: Here is the pic, sorry: https://ibb.co/cXQmT4W

Comment: Hey, why not using a plugin to create your custom blocks, right from your wp dashboard?! 
Here is a plugin [block-lab](https://wordpress.org/plugins/block-lab/)

Comment: Comments are perfectly fine for suggesting alternatives from the Plugin Repository. Please keep the comments respectful.

Comment: Yeah, sure, but that should be only when the suggested plugin is related and useful